# gain access to core WordPress functions

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i created a wordpress plugin but they sent me back some problems i must repair.
i used

```
<?php  
include '../../../wp-load.php';
?>
```

to gain access to core WordPress, byt they told me:

> It's best if you tie your processing functions into an action hook,
>   such as "init" or "admin_init".

but i found no good information on the web. i tried this:

```
<?php  
add_action('get_header', 'my_function_init');
?>
```

and other things i found on the web but nothing works like wp-load.php.

any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress won't let you get files from the system for that... it is a security breach.
The best you can get is admin_init.

read more here:
[Plugin API/Action Reference/admin init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init)

it gives you everything you need... what are the limits you are talking about?

Comment: my problem is that my plugin sends the user to an external file and in that file there are some wordpress veriables... i need the core of wordpress working on that external file... when i add wordpress functions he will not read them, he is running in my plugin folder outside of wordpress... this is why none of the add_action commands are working for me...

Comment: why won't you just move the files into the `wordpress/wp-content/plugins` folder?

Comment: this is my plugin:
http://zeevm.co.il/zeevmobile.zip
after loading the plugin files inside wordpress the plugin sends the user to an external page (to the file mobile-page.php) where he needs to run under wordpress... i did this with no problem untill they told me it's a bad idea. but i have no other option on how to do this. any advice ?

Comment: p.s. eliran, i'm israeli 2 :)

Comment: i will look into it now :)
btw: nice to know !

Comment: if i got it right: the plugin is just transferring the viewer to mobile site or normal site. why to do it like that?
what else does the plugin do?

Comment: in many sites like YNET,TAPUZ, WALLA and others this feature exist. people want to be able to transfer their users to a mobile app or whatever. this is what this plugin is for... i didn't found anything like it on wordpress ORG and i think it will help people.. so you have an advice on how to do this or you think it's the only way and i would argue that to the wordpress people ?

Comment: why not make it easyer?
js function to detect mobile browsing > custom page > session for choice.
the custom page is something you can put out as a html instead of the regular html load... you don't need to make pages like you have done.

Comment: but still, there is not problem with what you have done and it works.
the file is in the wp-content/plugin/plugin-name directory so lets make it work.
give me a few minutes i will find you the way.

Comment: ok so what i did was to change:
`<?php  
include '../../../wp-load.php';
?>`

to:
`<?php  
 $parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
 require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );
?>`

Comment: it should do it with them... i don't think they would tell you something :) though it's going around the problem but it just works and does it good and safe :)